# Undefined in console

Tags: express, nodemailer

I try to make seperate function for nodemailer and expecting boolean true or false in return.But when the mail is send to user I'm getting the mail in account but after that instead of true or false in return I'm getting value as undefined.

```
function nodeMailer(mailOptions){

 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: get.username,
            pass: get.password
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized : false
        }
    });


    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
       if(error) return false;

       return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined, because `true` or `false` should return your `nodeMailer` function and not `transporter.sendMail`.
In this case you can create `Promise` which can help you with that.

```
var nodeMailer = function(mailOptions) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: get.username,
                pass: get.password
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized : false
            }
        });


        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
           if(error) reject(error);

           resolve(info);
        });
       }
   });
}
```

and then call your promise like below

```
nodeMailer(yourOptions).then(function(result) {
    // handle success result here
    return info; 
})
.catch(function(err) {
     // handle your error here
})
```

more about promises you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They are very useful when you need to control your async flow.

Comment: I would suggest using `reject` in case of errors, and resolving `info` in case it worked okay.

Comment: Welcom, for more beautiful code, you can look at async/await of ES7, which is already supported by v8 without transpilers, more you can ready here https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly/

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using callback or promise.